# DurandalJS child routing clear subscription

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

On a page having child routers, I have a viewmodel with KnockoutJS bindings (KnockoutObservable). When I navigate on this page, I am able to validate that KnockoutObservable properties in my viewmodel have subscription, indicating they are binded. Via the Console, if I manually edit the KnockoutObservable value in the viewmodel, the displayed value in my view changes. Nothing exciting here...

But when navigation to child routes occurs, all subscriptions on "parent" routes are deleted, and when I try to manually edit the KnockoutObservable value in the console, it does not modify the displayed view.

Is it a normal behavior? Is this a bad design?

Comment: Not sure who upvoted this question but there is no code to show this issue so it is nearly impossible to try to help you here.

Comment: From your question I can only assume you are not familiar with durandal at all. My understanding is that you are wondering why one viewmodel isn't active on more views - that would be because each view should have it's own viewmodel.

Comment: I am currently building a VS solution sample for a proof on concept. It will be easier to understand (and explain!).

Comment: @Dominictus: Not necessarily; one can bind a composed view to the existing context, as demonstrated in the first example of visual composition in the [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/). It can even be useful.